# Get name of a random array from a JSON parent array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some JSON like this:

```
{"100":{"id":100,"name":"example"},"200":{"id":200,"name":"example2"}}
```

Which I converted to an array:

```
[100] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100
        [name] => "example"
    )

[200] => Array
    (
        [id] => 200
        [name] => "example"
    )
```

I want to return a random [id] - or a random array name because they are the same as the IDs. How can I do this?

I've tried:

```
$src  = "http://domain.com/json.json";
$data = file_get_contents($src);
$obj  = json_decode($data, true);
$rand = array_rand($obj);
echo strval($obj[$rand]);
```

Which outputs:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:/Users/Will/Documents/PHP/TestJson.php on line 7
Array
```

I want it to either output 100 or 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$jsonArr = json_decode($str, TRUE);
$rand_array_key = array_rand($jsonArr);
echo $jsonArr[$rand_array_key]['id'];
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101944)